# Не могу поместить данные в UITableView из Api

Tags: ios, swift, rest, uitableview

Всем привет, новичок на Swift, поэтому прошу помощи.
Не могу поместить данные в таблицу из API
Что делаю не правильно?

На странице API 20 персонажей, не могу перенести ни 1 данного в таблицу...
подскажите пожалуйста 
Вот код:

```
class UsersTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var jBonuses = [Results]()

 override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

    Loadchar()

}

func Loadchar() {
    let urlString = "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/"


    if let url = URL(string: urlString)
    {
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)

        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, responce, error) in
        if error != nil {
                   print(error!)
                   return
        }

            if let safeData = data {
                self.parseJson(weatherData: safeData)

            }
        }

        task.resume()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

func parseJson(weatherData: Data) {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    do {


        let decodedData = try decoder.decode(JSONData.self, from: weatherData)
        print(decodedData.results[0].name)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
 }


 struct JSONData: Decodable {
     let results: [Results]
 }
 struct Results: Decodable {
     let name: String

 }

 // MARK: - Table view data source
 override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
     return 1
 }

 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return jBonuses.count
 }

 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "user", for: indexPath)

    let news = jBonuses[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = news.name

    return cell
 }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

См. исправления в комментариях, вы получаете данные, но не присваиваете их массиву `jBonuses`

```
    func Loadchar() {
        let urlString = "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/"

        if let url = URL(string: urlString)
        {
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)

            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, responce, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error!)
                    return
                }

                if let safeData = data {
                    self.parseJson(weatherData: safeData)

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        // обновляем таблицу после получения данных в основном потоке
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            }

            task.resume()
        }
    }

    func parseJson(weatherData: Data) {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
            let decodedData = try decoder.decode(JSONData.self, from: weatherData)
            // получаем данные
            jBonuses = decodedData.results
            print(decodedData.results[0].name)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Помогло, спасибо за помощь!! Если можете, подскажите еще 1 момент, на APi откуда берутся данные 493 персонажа, но на одной странице отображается только 20, следующие идут character/?page=2 и /?page3 и т.д, как мне загрузить всех 493 персонажа в таблицу?

Comment: @Kyrylovep посмотрите АПИ сайта, возможно там указан способ загрузки всех персонажей одним списком, в противном случае можно грузить страницы последовательно, организовав например очередь загрузки или асинхронно (но это уже совсем иная история)

Comment: Я вот и смотрю, на сайте написано "Get all characters
You can access the list of characters by using the /character endpoint." Но на странице только 20 персонажей, и дальше они идут по страницам /character/page2 и т.д, подскажите куда смотреть, что бы грузить страницы последовательно?

Comment: @Kyrylovep вообще по-хорошему в таких случая неплохо сделать автоподгрузку по мере листания, чем грузить сразу всех персонажей, гуглим https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=swift+uitableview+load+more

Comment: Благодарю, буду смотреть и изучать!)